# How to make VS2012 run the last working version when a build fails.

Tags: visual-studio-2012

IN my **VS12**

When we hit **F5** it start **debugging**, un-fortunately I had **checked those check box (Remember my decision)** and hit on **no**.

But now even I want to start debugging VS12 automatically terminate this process, due to some errors....
How can I reenable the option to make Visual Studio run the last working version of the program when the build fails?

```
 I had tried to check VS debugging setting but I could not find anything....
```

Comment: Please update your question to include the specific errors you are seeing.

Comment: The question is regarding, to VS 12 setting, so, there is no any code, and error.....
And I don't think that for this question i need to put code...

Comment: Ask somebody close by to look over your shoulder.  It is probably something silly like your code not compiling or your program instantly completing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run.

Then change the value of "On Run, when build or deployment errors occur:" to "Prompt to launch".